# setFocus in JSF2 (Mojarra)

Tags: jsf-2

I want to set focus on commandButton field in JSF2(Mojarra) on page load.    How can I implement this without using Javascript? Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: I really doubt you can do it without JS. At the very best, you can wrap it with a tag like here: https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/components/onloadScript.xhtml

Comment: You can also open an enhancement issue on omni faces http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/list , to request the `highlight` component to be duplicated + modified into a focus elemnt https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/components/highlight.xhtml :) Also , take a look at this http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How can I implement this **without** using Javascript?*

This is only possible when the browser supports HTML5. You can then use the new HTML5 `autofocus` attribute so that you ultimately end up with

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" autofocus="true" />
```

This attribute is not supported by the JSF `<h:commandButton>` component. Adding arbitrary attributes to JSF components like `<h:commandButton autofocus="true">` is also not natively supported by JSF, it would be plain ignored. You'd basically need to create a custom tag/component which supports the new attribute.

You can also use a custom [`RenderKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/RenderKit.html) to write unsupported attributes anyway. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has since version 1.3 a [`Html5RenderKit`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit) for exactly this purpose.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" autofocus="true" />
```

Again, this works only in browsers supporting HTML5 `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: @BalusC This sounds pretty damn great. It reminds me of the new HTML5 friendly markup for jsf 2.2.

Comment: @BalusC How can set auto focus in `jsf` to a `input text` when page is loaded, without `javascript` or `primefaces` ?